# How to make plotly python subplots have the same color and legend for the corresponding data?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

My problem is that I have this plot, and the traces with the same on different subplots will have a different color and a separate legend. The color issue can be solved easily by manually overwriting them, but that does not solve the legend. I phrased the question such, because it feels like there is a solution that should take care of both at the same time.

Code:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)

# add some data
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="blue", x=["a","b"], y=[1,2]),
              row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="red", x=["a","b"], y=[3,1]),
              row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="blue", x=["a","b"], y=[2,3]),
              row=2, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="red", x=["a","b"], y=[1,4]),
              row=2, col=1)

fig.update_layout(height=600, width=400, showlegend=True)

fig.show()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Plotly creates a legend for each graph, so naturally the color of the legend will change. To make it consistent, you can specify the color of the marker. The code is as follows. `fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="blue", x=["a","b"], y=[1,2], marker=dict(color='blue')), row=1, col=1);fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="red", x=["a","b"], y=[3,1], marker=dict(color='red')), row=1, col=1);fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="blue", x=["a","b"], y=[2,3], marker=dict(color='blue'), showlegend=False), row=2, col=1);fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="red", x=["a","b"], y=[1,4], marker=dict(color='red'), showlegend=False), ...)`

Comment: As mentioned in the question, the color issue is solved easily, but that does not solve the legend issue.

Comment: Did you ask for a grouping of legends? If so, then your answer is correct, but what is its purpose?

Comment: I didn't exactly know what I was looking for. If I did, I wouldn't have asked. The _"same legend"_ and the _"My problem is that ... the traces ... have .... a separate legend"_ definitely hints at that.

This way if you click one of the rows in the legend, they will be taken off the plot. Without grouping, you would have to do them separately.

Comment: I finally understand your intention. +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually define color `marker=dict(color='red')`, the legend group `legendgroup="red"`, and implicitly say that you don't want the legend to be displayed on the second appearance for each color `showlegend=False` (you need to have them present at least once if you want to appear correctly, and you have multiple of each color otherwise).

The corrected code:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)

# add some data
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="blue", x=["a","b"], y=[1,2], marker=dict(color='blue'), legendgroup="blue"),
              row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="red", x=["a","b"], y=[3,1], marker=dict(color='red'), legendgroup="red"),
              row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="blue", x=["a","b"], y=[2,3], marker=dict(color='blue'), legendgroup="blue", showlegend=False),
              row=2, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="red", x=["a","b"], y=[1,4], marker=dict(color='red'), legendgroup="red", showlegend=False),
              row=2, col=1)

fig.update_layout(height=600, width=400, showlegend=True)

fig.show()
```

[image: plot]